# Loading a sound with kivy on my Android device

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, audio, kivy

SOLVED

I have a kivy application that plays a sound. It works fine on GNU/Linux but the app crashes on my Android device. Here are a few lines from the command : buildozer android_new debug deploy run logcat

```
V/SDL     (29083): SDL audio: opening device
V/SDL     (29083): SDL audio: wanted stereo 16-bit 44.1kHz, 4096 frames buffer
I/AudioPolicyManager( 2267): getOutputForAttr() device 0x2, samplingRate 44100, format afcad8d8, channelMask 1, flags 0
I/AudioPolicyManager( 2267): getOutputForAttr() output 2
W/AudioPolicyIntefaceImpl( 2267): Skipped to add effects on session 182
I/AudioPolicyManager( 2267): startOutput() output 2, stream 3, session 182
I/AudioPolicyManager( 2267): changeRefCount() stream 3, count 1
I/AudioPolicyManager( 2267): setOutputDevice() setting same device 0002 or null device for output 2
V/SDL     (29083): SDL audio: got stereo 16-bit 44.1kHz, 4096 frames buffer
I/python  (29083): [WARNING] [AudioSDL2   ] Unable to load sounds/applause.wav: Mix_LoadWAV_RW with NULL src
D/AudioMixer( 2267): setResampler format 1, data ch 2, src 44100, dst 48000, dnmix 0, reformat 0
D/SoundAliveResampler( 2267): [SoundAliveResampler] Init+++
I/AudioHardwareTinyALSA( 2267): AudioStreamOutALSA::write setDevice
D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA( 2267): OutALSA::setDevice: mode = 0, newDevice=0x2, currentDevice=0x2 ,force= 0
D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA( 2267): OutALSA::setDevice: mDevice 0x2, newDevice = 0x2
D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA( 2267): setOutputVolume
D/TinyUCM ( 2267): setModifier Normal, en=1
I/AudioHardwareTinyALSA( 2267): OutALSA::setDevice: mHandle NULL mode[0], Device[00000002] nDevice:3 
I/AudioHardwareTinyALSA( 2267): Open:+ mDefaults->direction=0 device=3
D/AudioHardwareTinyALSA( 2267): Channel: 2, Samplerate: 48000, Format: 0, Period Size: 960, Period Count: 4
```

Here is the piece of python code I have for that :

```
######################################### snip
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
sound = SoundLoader.load('sounds/applause.wav')
sound.play()
######################################### snip
```

It couldn't be simpler.

On GNU/Linux the kivy app works very well but it crashes on my Samsung Android tablet when trying to load the sound.

Any advice would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: use `adb logcat -s python` to see the raised exception. `adb` is in your sdk platform-tools folder.

Comment: I have nothing more than what I published earlier. The only line I got is : I/python  (31447): [WARNING] [AudioSDL2   ] Unable to load sounds/applause.wav: Mix_LoadWAV_RW with NULL src

Comment: On python/linux side everything is OK. The problem comes from Android and AudioSDL2. One question though : what is "NULL src"? I will try with another wav file. Perhaps the file is not good enough for Android.

Comment: @Juggernaut With another audio file I get the same error. And nothing on python side. No exception was raised on python side. So the problem comes from Android. adb gives me only one relevant line, the same as before : [WARNING] [AudioSDL2   ] Unable to load sounds/12926_sweet_trip_mm_sweep_y.wav: Mix_LoadWAV_RW with NULL src

Comment: The best I can guess is that NULL src means the path to file is invalid.
Try providing an absolute path using `os.path.abspath` and try again

Comment: Thank you @Juggernaut. Your idea helped me to get into the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just solved my problem!

It was so simple : why didn't I think about that?!

Well the solution was to set the file suffix into buildozer.spec at the line "source.include_exts".